# Array of X- and Y-coordinates - How to store data arrays in scripts?

Tags: arrays, dm-script

I have an image of atomic columns and I want to store the X- and Y-coordinates of maximum value of each atomic column but I don't know how to write the script to store bunch of data as an array. Please help me.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Do you mean you need help with storing multiple XY values (in an array), or with *finding* these values from the image?

Comment: @BmyGuest sorry if my question is not clear. Yes, I do mean by storing multiple XY values in an array.

Comment: @BmyGuest Thank you for suggesting a clearer question title! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I unstand the question, but if you are just looking to store multiple values in an "array" then you just need to recognize that any 2D image already *is* an array. If you want to store n XY-pair values, then you can simple create a [n x 2] image and store the values there. Some example:

```
number n = 30       // number of pairs
image data := Realimage( "Data Array", 4, 2 , n )

for( number i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
    number xValue = i * 10                              // just something
    number yValue = xValue * sin( xValue / 100 * PI() )     // just something
    data.SetPixel(0, i, xValue )                // Set X at position i (first column)
    data.SetPixel(1, i, YValue )                // Set Y at position i (second column)
}

data.ShowImage()

// You may want to display the image as "Spreadsheet". (Type 7)
data.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).ImageDisplayChangeDisplayType(7)

// And you may want to label the columns
data.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).SpreadSheetImageDisplaySetColumnLabel( 0, "X values" )
data.ImageGetImageDisplay(0).SpreadSheetImageDisplaySetColumnLabel( 1, "Y values" )
```

[image: Image displayed as spread-sheet]

You don't have to use `SetPixel()`. You can also set pixel values by indexing the position.

```
 data[0, i] = xValue // Same as: data.SetPixel( 0, i, xValue )
```

Comment: @Aning: Great. I just want to add to this, that depending on your further aims with that list, another option would be to store the data in TagGroups or TagLists. There are some advantages (like easier "sorting" and ammending new - non scalar value - data) but also disadvantages (images can be used in image-expression calculations which are way faster than relying to single-value extraction).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Actually, later (in a separate script) I need to refer back and use the XY values that are stored in the array. Is it possible to do that? (I am sorry if, again, my question is not clear as I am not good in English. sorry)

Comment: Yes, you simply use "GetPixel" instead of "SetPixel". But depending on how you need these numbers - just one of them, or all one-by-one - there might be more efficient ways to use `image expressions` instead.

Comment: I would like to ask.. Is it possible to *call* arrays in a separate script with the one that was used to create arrays? (Sorry for my messy English. I mean, say, arrays are created in script A. I want to call these arrays in script B) Is it possible?

Comment: @Aning Maybe you should ask differnt things in separate questions so that they can be searched for by others more easily. But as a quick answer: If you display an image, it stays open and in memory when the script finishes, so another script can start with that image. Alternativly, you can store an image (or info) in the Global tags (or on disk). Finally, you can write one single script with multiple functions and then have this single script do all of it. The best solution very much depends on what you want to do.